# Quadratic sequence for non-uniform structured mesh generation

Tags: sequences-and-series, python, meshing

Here's a problem I've been trying to tackle for a while... I have a 1D `numpy` array/list/sequence of numbers, like so:

[image: 1]

However, there is a certain condition my sequence has to meet: the y-displacement shall not exceed a factor of 2x (relative to the neighbouring point/element). For example, this particular sequence does not meet this requirement in certain indices:

[image: 2]

- **Green:** OK
- **Red:** Not OK; exceeds a factor of $2$

The goal is to modify the array (ideally with as few insertions of new elements as possible), so that the steps are not as steep, and the <2x condition is met. Any ideas how one might do this?

I've tried a few things with `np.linspace` and squaring it (`**2`) to produce a quadratic sequence, but I haven't fully figured it out yet.

In its original visual, the problem looks like this (X axis only) - the goal is to generate a grid (mesh) to a structure for physics simulations, and >2x steps should generally be avoided:

[image: 3]

Comment: I don't understand the condition about the $y$ displacement and the factor of $2x$. What is $x$? Or is that times? It would help if you could make precise this condition

Comment: @Sal It is "times" indeed. Does that make things a bit clearer?

Comment: I think an example may help. Let $y_n$ be the sequence of numbers. In the second plot $y_7\approx -37$ and $y_8 \approx-32$. How exactly does this fail your condition?

Comment: @Sal You also need to consider $y_6$ (or $y_9$, depending on which neighbor you look at), because $\frac{y_8-y_7}{y_7-y_6} > 2$. By y-displacement I'm referring to the y value relative to the previous element (i.e. how much it increased by).